# How to insert HTML text inside a JavaFX shape?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to create a tree-based algorithm visualization in JavaFx, and there are many sub scripts and super scripts in the notations. I want to add these notations to shapes like circles.

I have tried using WebView object for doing that, but it just covers up the entire screen.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        primaryStage.setTitle("Shape Text");
        Group circles = new Group();
        Circle circle = new Circle(50, Color.web("white", 0.7));
        circle.setCenterX(500.0f);
        circle.setCenterY(200.0f);
        circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.web("white", 0.16));
        circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
        circles.getChildren().add(circle);

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<h1>B<sub>0</sub></h1>");

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(circles, webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 1000, 800, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

The above code replaces the entire view with HTML text. I also tried javafx.scene.text.Text class, but it does not support the HTML content.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If all of your superscripts and subscripts are digits, you don’t need a WebView.  You can use plain text, since Unicode includes characters for superscripted and subscripted digits.  For instance, `new Label("B\u2080")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three things you might want to do:

1. [Size the WebView to the HTML content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838965/size-javafx-webview-to-the-minimum-size-needed-by-the-document-body) (or the inner display region of the shape).
2. Make the [background of the WebView pages transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421250/transparent-background-in-the-webview-in-javafx).
3. [Center the HTML content in the WebView](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_center-vertical.asp), with the WebView centered in the Shape.

[image: sized webview]

Code below demonstrates some of these tricks:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ShapedHTML extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{
        stage.setTitle("Shape Text");
        Group circles = new Group();
        Circle circle = new Circle(50, Color.web("white", 0.7));
        circle.setCenterX(500.0f);
        circle.setCenterY(200.0f);
        circle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.OUTSIDE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.web("white", 0.16));
        circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
        circles.getChildren().add(circle);

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webView.maxWidthProperty().bind(circle.radiusProperty().multiply(2));
        webView.maxHeightProperty().bind(circle.radiusProperty().multiply(2));
        webEngine.documentProperty().addListener(observable -> {                   
            try {
                // Use reflection to retrieve the WebEngine's private 'page' field.
                Field f = webEngine.getClass().getDeclaredField("page");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                com.sun.webkit.WebPage page = (com.sun.webkit.WebPage) f.get(webEngine);
                page.setBackgroundColor((new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0, 0)).getRGB());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Difficulty to make WebView background transparent");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        webEngine.loadContent("<h1 id='root' style='background : rgba(0,0,0,0); margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);'>B<sub>0</sub></h1>");

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(circles, webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 1000, 800, Color.BLACK);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*Note on `com.sun` class usage*

The above code uses `com.sun` classes (which is usually not recommended as it is not publicly supported API).  But, it worked for me (on Java 8) and I don't know a better way to accomplish the transparency of the WebView background.

If you are using later versions of Java (e.g. Java 11+), then you will need to provide some VM arguments to allow usage of the relevant `com.sun` classes to work.  See, for instance, the stack overflow question [Cannot access JavaFX class "WebPage" in IntelliJ-IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999389/cannot-access-javafx-class-webpage-in-intellij-idea) for resolving accessibility issues for `com.sun.webkit.WebPage` in Java 11+.  An answer to that question suggests using the following VM arguments (which I haven't tried):

```
--add-exports javafx.web/com.sun.webkit=projectname
```

where the last argument is your module name as declared in the `module-info.java` of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `maxSize` of the `WebView`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXTestingGround extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Circle circle = new Circle(100, Color.web("white", 0.7));

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.loadContent("<h1>B<sub>0</sub></h1>");
        webView.setMaxSize(50, 50);

        StackPane stack = new StackPane();
        stack.getChildren().addAll(circle, webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 1000, 800, Color.BLACK);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]